# Pixellated Text on Magazine psd Mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

I'm new to photoshop mockups to present my work. I can't figure out why the smaller text in the mockup isn't sharp, or the whole image in fact. I've been saving as a jpeg and then viewing at 100%. The PDFs I'm putting into the smart object layers are perfectly sharp. Is there something I'm missing? The files I'm putting into the layers were produced in InDesign, saved as PDF, then dragged into the relevant layer.

[image: Here's a section of the mockup that shows the pixellated text.]

Thanks.

Comment: So what you're asking is why the stuff that's about the same size as a pixel, but that isn't lined up with the pixels, isn't sharp?

Comment: How big or sharp the input is isn't going to make a huge amount of difference if the mockup is low res

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your document's specs'it's a guesssing game. But if I had to guess, I would say the resolution of your mockup is too low.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I know what's problem here, it's not on you - it's Photoshop problem. Try to increase a size of a placeholder where you paste your design. After you paste a design, decrease a placeholder size to the original and that should be solution for your problem.

Comment: can you explain how to increase / decrease the placeholder size?